# What less files should i include to use twitter bootstrap tabs?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using twitter bootstrap tabs and i want to load only the CSS needed for them, what should i load?Right now i'm using

```
  @import "reset.less";

  // Core variables and mixins
  @import "variables.less"; // Modify this for custom colors, font-sizes, etc

  @import "mixins.less";

  // Grid system and page structure
  //@import "scaffolding.less";
  //@import "grid.less";
  //@import "layouts.less";

  // Base CSS
  @import "type.less";
  //@import "code.less";
  //@import "forms.less";
  //@import "tables.less";

  // Components: common
  //@import "sprites.less";
  //@import "dropdowns.less";
  @import "wells.less";
  //@import "component-animations.less";
  //@import "close.less";

  // Components: Buttons & Alerts
  @import "buttons.less";
  //@import "button-groups.less";
  //@import "alerts.less"; // Note: alerts share common CSS with buttons and thus have styles in buttons.less

  // Components: Nav
  @import "navs.less";
  @import "navbar.less";
  //@import "breadcrumbs.less";
  //@import "pagination.less";
  //@import "pager.less";

  // Components: Popovers
  //@import "modals.less";
  //@import "tooltip.less";
  //@import "popovers.less";

  // Components: Misc
  //@import "thumbnails.less";
  //@import "labels.less";
  //@import "badges.less";
  //@import "progress-bars.less";
  //@import "accordion.less";
  //@import "carousel.less";
  @import "hero-unit.less";

  // Utility classes
  @import "utilities.less"; // Has to be last to override when necessary
```

Do i need more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's enough, use these less file for all types of navs and tabs

```
navs.less, mixin.less,
```

But it also depends upon styling of your tabs, If possible show me that styling

Comment: It's the standard styling http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs but i guess youare right and it's enough

Comment: is anything else regarding bootstrap bro?

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is old and answered, in case anyone stumbles upon this with some google-fu all you actually need, if you're going to style them yourself anyway, is the following.

```
.tab-content {
    > .tab-pane {
        display: none;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    > .active {
        display: block;
        visibility: visible;
    }
}
```